# Проблема с подключением компонента vue-mapbox

Tags: vue.js, mapbox

Сделал все по [инструкции](https://soal.github.io/vue-mapbox/) на чистом проекте и никаких проблем. Но когда импортирую пакет в уже существующем проекте происходит непонятное:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/vue-mapbox/src/components/layer/GeojsonLayer.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (110:10)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|         const source = {
|           type: "geojson",
|           ...this.source
|         };
|         try {
 @ ./node_modules/vue-mapbox/src/main.js 11:0-59
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/drivers/Testmap.vue
 @ ./src/components/drivers/Testmap.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

Никак не могу понять, что происходит. Может кто подскажет :)

Comment: babel должен его прожевать

Comment: А что мне надо для этого сделать?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рабочая гипотеза: Vue-loader v14 не дружит с компонентом VueMapbox. А 15-ую версию завести не удалось. Так что видимо придется отказаться от компонента и прикручивать mapbox вручную.

Comment: Оказалось так и есть